How do I build an image with the signed new certificate of Windows UEFI CA 2023
I have been trying using the ADK from Windows, as well as the MDT but I made an image and checked the EFI certificate and it is still 2011. I was following the steps by Microsoft for the Black Lotus Mitigation and honestly think that, that works for building a WinPE Environment Image (I may be wrong... probably am wrong...). I feel hesitant, and searching on the web I have not found a resource that clearly outlines how to create a Installation Media, at least a vanilla image that I can use as a mitigation strategy. I was wondering if I am the only one facing the same problem or if this is simply to complicated for me and I am missing the point. Is there a method for creating a installation media that is Windows 11 24H2 OS for with a signed EFI file for Windows UEFI CA 2023?
Update
I am able now to mount the EFI partition and was able to get certificate that matches Windows UEFI CA 2023. I am going now to try to create the recovery disk with steps provided.
Source WebPage
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5025885-how-to-manage-the-windows-boot-manager-revocations-for-secure-boot-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932-41a975df-beb2-40c1-99a3-b3ff139f832d

@Ramhound I just followed the document and I managed to mount my EFI partition and checked the cert is now 2023

@Ramhound I managed to follow the steps outlined in the Microsoft article; however, I am still unsure how to create installation media with the efi file that was created as I am much oblivious and ignorant to this topic. I will do research though and see what else I can find.

@Ramhound Okay I have the new EFI file now I want to make an image with it do I use MDT and just prepare the image as normal and use that EFI file for new image I make if I want to use RUFUS to burn it onto a USB? Or Img Burn if I want to make it an ISO file?

You should be able to replace the EFI file contained within the ISO, I don’t think that part is explicitly stated since it’s implied. Why don’t you just wait for Microsoft to push the update?
